# Regex in Java: find all instances of [char1] but only if they are not preceded by [char2]

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have the following method, where I want the regex given to the split method to find all instances of the comma character (","), if if is not preceded by letter "x".

The method:

```
public void replaceTest3() {
        String valueRaw = "onex,two,three,fourx,five";
        String[] splittedString = valueRaw.split("[(.,)]&&[^x{1}+,]");
        for (int i = 0; i < splittedString.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(splittedString[i]);
        }
}
```

So I would expect this method to output

```
onex,two
three
fourx,five
```

However, as the regex currently is, the latter part to exclude all instances of commas preceded by "x" doesn't work - apparently nothing is found. Where is my error and how could I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> find all instances of the comma character (","), if if is not
>   preceeded by letter "x".

Could be done with a negative lookbehind like this:

```
(?<!x),
```

I.e:

```
valueRaw.split("(?<!x),");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your character classes are bogus. Special characters lose their meaning inside character classes. For example, `[(.,)]&&[^x{1}+,]` matches "`(&&+", ")&&{`", ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with some more code, this is a solution without look-behinds:

```
private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile( "[^x],|^," );
private static List<String> splitAtCommaNotPreceededByX( String valueRaw ) {
    Matcher m = P.matcher( valueRaw );
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        parts.add( valueRaw.substring( start, m.end() - 1 ) );
        start = m.end();
    }
    parts.add( valueRaw.substring( start ) );
    return parts;
}
```